# Need <input> to also scroll to section ID

Tags: html

I've got an input that fires a jQuery toggle to switch between content in two different divs... two separate menus in this case.

Because one menu is much longer than the other, I placed that input within an a-tag that scrolls up to the top of container so if the user is at the bottom of the long menu and then switches to the short menu, they're not stuck way at the bottom of the container.  One menu is quite long, especially on mobile viewports.

Everything works exactly as intended, but it's throwing an HTML5 validation error because an a-tag can't contain an input.

Any suggestions on keeping the functionality but eliminating the error?

**The HTML:**

```
<section id="menu-bin">
    <div id="menu-1">
        <!--  A Bunch of Menu Content -->
    </div>
    <div id="menu-1">
        <!--  A Bunch of Menu Content -->
    </div>       
</section>

<div class="button-switches">
    <a class="scrolly" href="#menu-bin">
    <!-- Forces scroll to top of menu (important for mobile) -->
    <input id="menu-switch1" type="button" value="Switch Menus" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply don't use the `input` (P.S style the `a` like one)

Comment: Dammit...  =).  I need to stop staring at this project.  Thank you!